# Hash table: How to use members declared in a header file in a different header file

Tags: c++, data-structures, hashtable, header-files, declaration

I do apologize if this is a duplicate question. I did some searching and while most of them referred to using class members in different cpp files, I did not find any asking about header files. The main.cpp does insert both header files.

I am using two header files, let's refer to them as Acode and Bcode with classes A and B.

Acode.h header file consists of

```
template<typename X, typename Y>
class A{
public:
X key;
Y value;
bool isempty;
bool isremoved;

A<X,Y>(){
empty = true;
isremoved = false;
}

A<X,Y>(const X& input, const Y& input2){
key = input;
value = input2;
isempty = true;
isremoved = false;
}
```

Bcode.h header file uses the A class from the Acode.h file

```
template<typename X, typename Y>
class B{
public:
B(){
size = 80;
elem = 0;
table = new A<X,Y>[80];
};
//other unimportant functions

private:
int size, elem;
A<X,Y>* table; //this is the hash table 
//other unimportant variables
```

I want to be able to use class members declared in the public function of Acode.h. From here on, I know everything I did is incorrect, but I do not know how to fix it.

```
class B{
//along with the codes mentioned above
public:
A<X,Y>* get_key(){
return key;
}

A<X,Y>* get_value(){
return value;
}

A<X,Y>* B<X,Y>::search(const X& key);
```

I tried to use these in a different function like

```
A<X,Y>* B<X,Y>::search(const X& key){
int hashindex = hashfunction(key); //this is the hash function declared elsewhere in the code
if(table[hashindex].get_key() == key)
return table[hashindex].get_value();
}
```

I keep getting the error message
error: ‘key’ was not declared in this scope; (along with value)
error: ‘class B, int>’ has no member named ‘get_key’

I am trying to use the members from A class but it seems like a commenter mentioned, I first need to create an instance of the class? But I thought declaring A<X,Y>* table would have been enough. Is this logic incorrect? (I'm assuming it might be). Also, since get_key is not associated with type B, int, what can I do in order to try and resolve this?

**Edit**
I figured it out thank you for helping everybody.

Comment: You need to create an instance of the object. They’re not variables in a header file, they’re members of the class. If you don’t have an object you don’t have any variables either.

Comment: Oh I think that makes a lot more sense. Yes, I did mean to refer to them has members not variables so I apologize for that.

Comment: please show a [mre] and include the full text of any error messages

Comment: I edited the entire question to try to make it more reproducible and more in-depth.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access and set the values of `removed` and `empty` with in the member functions of class B.

But in class B, you can add a method to access key as below.

```
X* get_key(){
return key;
}
```

Comment: Oh, so I wouldn't declare get_key() as A<X,Y>* get_key() but rather X* get_key()? Can you explain this a little more, please? Thank you very much for the response

Comment: Since the datatype of key is 'X', only 'X' as the return type is fine.